# How to scroll cells only and not the entire tableview?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

How do you disable tableview scrolling but enable cells to scroll within the section similar to how path for iPad  does their friend and and notification cells, they are collapsable but the cells under the section only scroll within the section as in the section does not move to the top of the device but remains in its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such controls available in iOS.

Possibly it is a customized `UITableView`. According to your description, each section of that table will contain another `UITableView` not simple `UITableViewCell`. That's why it have the feature you specified.

I had seen some open-source controls with similar feature, but forgot the name of those controls.

Comment: Yes I think I will go the multiple tableview route, thanks.

Comment: @EdwardSeshoka: Thanks for your comment. All the best !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, its better if you can add more details. But I will give you a rough answer to my understanding of your problem. What you can do is use UITextView in side your tableview cell and depending on the scenarion you can disable the scroll. It is recommended you keep only one scroll view scrollable at one time. UITableView is also inherits from UIScrollView. You can set the scroll disabling to your gesture handle methods or in a expanded cell scenario. To set scroll disable you can set   scrollEnabled property to no.

Refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView

Comment: Well the default behavior of tableview section scrolling is to basically anchor the section at the top by floating it from its initial position and then scroll cells within the section until another section comes in to view, What I want to do is keep the section at its position not float it to the top, but still be able to scroll cells within the section as you would when its anchored at the top, I am not sure if that's a bit clear?

Comment: what you can do is to have a delegation to process the scroll focus. Using scrolling delegate methods you can identify the bounds and disable enable scroll accordingly.